# Entry point classes not found (GWT + GAE + Eclipse )

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I got the following error when i try to deploy my application to GAE.

`jul 05, 2014 2:51:37 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Compiling module com.sertaogames.cangaco.CangacoRPG
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.sertaogames.cangaco.cleint.CangacoRPG'
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.sertaogames.cangaco.cleint.CangacoRPG' is really what you meant
         [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots`

It is running smoothly from localhost

The file exists (com.sertaogames.cangaco.cleint.CangacoRPG) and was created default by eclipse.
.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you included all of your dependencies in /war/WEB-INF/ lib/ directory. It's not enough to add them to your classpath.

In Eclipse you may see a warning in the Problems tab that a class is not going to be available on server.